# Is it possible to duplicate a row in grafana?

Tags: graphite, grafana

I want to have many rows on the same dashboard which are very similar, so row duplication would prove very handy.

However from what i can see it's only possible to duplicate a panel.

So is it possible to duplicate a row (consisting of multiple panels)?

Comment: There is a feature-suggestion you are interested in: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/1004 And the PR that will solve that thing: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/1920

Comment: Thx @kAlmAcetA, so i'll take that there's no straight forward way..

Comment: Have you tried exporting the JSON and copy pasting the rows you need a couple times?  You can then just import the JSON and save it over the existing dashboard

Comment: The Json edit method: Click on 'Manage Dashboard' -> 'View JSON'. Cut and paste all of the JSON to the left hand pane on this Json editor: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/. Click the arrow pointing to the right to populate the data view. You can duplicate rows quite easily, you can even duplicate or remove panels, but you may want to use Grafana for that. Once happy, click the left arrow to re-generate Json, cut and paste it into 'Import Dashboard' in Grafana. A bit cumbersome, but it works!

Answer (score 5):

**Note**: This project has been unmaintained for years and no longer works with recent versions of Grafana.

---

You can use `wizzy` to duplicate a row on a Grafana dashboard:

```
wizzy copy row 1 2
```

Here are the links for getting starting with wizzy:

https://github.com/utkarshcmu/wizzy

https://utkarshcmu.github.io/wizzy-site/home/getting-started/#installation

Comment: this doesnt work with the latest version 7 of grafana. Summarize even shows the wrong row count

Comment: Please delete this answer, it proposes an outdated, unmaintained tool.

Answer (score 3):

You can. First create a template: On your dashboard click settings, `Templating` and create your template variable.

Next, in your panel click on the green bar, `Row Editor`, select `Repeat Row` and put your template-variable there.

There is a nice gif-example here underneath "Repeating Rows and Panels": 
http://docs.grafana.org/guides/whats-new-in-v2-1/

Comment: if you still active, do you have an example dashboard who repeat panel ? Because despite I used the option "repeat row" my row doesn't repeat herself...

Comment: The link in my answer does not help you? 

Do you have grafana version >= 2.1 ? 
You do need to have values in your template variable, and then you need to select them.

Comment: yes after reading a bit I was able to make it works ! I upvote yours

Answer (score 0):

Per [How to automatically repeat rows and panels in dynamic dashboards](https://grafana.com/blog/2020/06/09/learn-grafana-how-to-automatically-repeat-rows-and-panels-in-dynamic-dashboards/)

- Edit the panel by clicking the title of the panel, and click Edit.
- In the panel editor, open the Repeat options section.
- In Repeat by variable, select the instance variable.
- In Repeat direction, select Horizontal to lay out the repeated panels horizontally.
- Apply your changes to go back to the dashboard.
- Click Add panel, and then click Convert to row. The panels you created earlier are automatically assigned to the row you created.
- Hover your cursor over the Row title and click the gear icon to open the Row Options.
- In Title, enter $service.
- In Repeat for, select the variable you want to repeat rows for. For this example, select service.
- Click Update.
- Select multiple services from the service drop-down menu. Grafana creates a row for each selected service, each within its own set of repeated panels.
- Find the left-most panel in the top-most row and edit it.
- In the text area for the Text panel, enter $instance and $service.
- Save the dashboard and refresh the page.